# Bash: Cut a CSV File from specific Column Names

Tags: bash, csv, cut

I got a CSV File with a lot of useless information, and I want the information that i need from that file into another CSV File.

Current State:

```
First Name,Middle Name, Last Name, Title, Suffix, Nickname, Given Yomi, Surname Yomi....
Angel,,Romero,,,Romi,, ....
```

In new File Should be something like:

```
First Name, Last Name, Nickname
Angel, Romero, Romi
```

I want to do that by using something like cut and the Column names, not just the Field numbers.
Like this somehow:

```
cut -d',' -f"First Name" file
```

I know that doesn't work but is there another way?

Comment: As you don't need reordering, `cut -d ',' -f '1,3,6'` is enough

Comment: You asked [the exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70244801/bash-save-certain-column-entries-into-a-new-cvs-file). Please edit your original question instead of opening a new one

Comment: "I want to do that by using something like cut and the Column names, not just the Field numbers." Why? If that's really what you want, try SQL. Should be reasonably easy to import into any small DB.

Comment: The [csvcut](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvcut.html) command from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does exactly this: `csvcut -Sc 'First Name','Last Name' file.csv`

Comment: @glennjackman I tried that but it always tells me 'csvcut: command not found' even tho i installed csvkit

Comment: Your CSV separator and inconsistent. Some have spaces: `, `  and some do not: `,`. Is this what your actual file looks like or is that just a bad example?

Comment: @dawg bad example. would be without spaces

Comment: Where did csvkit get installed? Is that directory in your PATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool is [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/):

```
mlr --csv cut -o -f "field A","field B" input.csv >output.csv
```

[Here](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs/index.html#cut) the documentation for `cut` verb.

Comment: for some reason I can't install the tool..

Comment: @MahmoudAbdulkarim what's your operative system? What errors did you have during the installation?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v tags='First Name,Last Name,Nickname' '
    BEGIN {
        FS=", *"; OFS=", "
        numOutFlds = split(tags,outFldNr2tag)
    }
    NR==1 {
        for (inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++) {
            tag = $inFldNr
            tag2inFldNr[tag] = inFldNr
        }
    }
    {
        for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
            tag = outFldNr2tag[outFldNr]
            inFldNr = tag2inFldNr[tag]
            val = $inFldNr
            printf "%s%s", val, (outFldNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
' file
First Name, Last Name, Nickname
Angel, Romero, Romi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat csvcut.awk
# csvcut.awk

function csvsplit(str, arr,     i,j,n,s,fs,qt) {
    # split comma-separated fields into arr; return number of fields in arr
    # fields surrounded by double-quotes may contain commas;
    #     doubled double-quotes represent a single embedded quote
    delete arr; s = "START"; n = 0; fs = ","; qt = "\""
    for (i = 1; i <= length(str); i++) {
        if (s == "START") {
            if (substr(str,i,1) == fs) { arr[++n] = "" }
            else if (substr(str,i,1) == qt) { j = i+1; s = "INQUOTES" }
            else { j = i; s = "INFIELD" } }
        else if (s == "INFIELD") {
            if (substr(str,i,1) == fs) {
                arr[++n] = substr(str,j,i-j); j = 0; s = "START" } }
        else if (s == "INQUOTES") {
            if (substr(str,i,1) == qt) { s = "MAYBEDOUBLE" } }
        else if (s == "MAYBEDOUBLE") {
            if (substr(str,i,1) == fs) {
                arr[++n] = substr(str,j,i-j-1)
                gsub(qt qt, qt, arr[n]); j = 0; s = "START" } } }
    if (s == "INFIELD" || s == "INQUOTES") { arr[++n] = substr(str,j) }
    else if (s == "MAYBEDOUBLE") {
        arr[++n] = substr(str,j,length(str)-j); gsub(qt qt, qt, arr[n]) }
    else if (s == "START") { arr[++n] = "" }
    return n }

BEGIN { # read and store output field names
    for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) { fields[++nfields] = ARGV[i]; ARGV[i] = "" } }

NR == 1 { # read and store input field names, write output header
    for (i=1; i<=csvsplit($0,arr); i++) { names[arr[i]] = i }
    for (i=1; i<=nfields; i++) { printf "%s%s", sep, fields[i]; sep = "," }
    printf "\n" }

NR > 1 { # read input record, split fields, write output record
    delete csv; sep = ""; n = csvsplit($0, csv)
    for (i=1; i<=nfields; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", sep, csv[names[fields[i]]]; sep = "," }
    printf "\n" }
$ cat mahmoud.input
FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Title,Suffix,Nickname,GivenYomi,SurnameYomi
Angel,,Romero,,,Romi,,
$ awk -f csvcut.awk FirstName LastName Nickname <mahmoud.input
FirstName,LastName,Nickname
Angel,Romero,Romi
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have a straight CSV without the variable space, you can use Ruby's csv parser directly (without cleaning the csv file first...)

Given:

```
cat file
First Name,Middle Name,Last Name,Title,Suffix,Nickname,Given Yomi,Surname Yomi
Angel,,Romero,,,Romi,,
```

You can just filter each csv row:

```
ruby -r CSV -e 'BEGIN{wanted=["First Name", "Last Name", "Nickname"]
                      puts wanted.to_csv
                      }     
CSV.parse($<.read, headers:true).each{
    |h| puts h.to_hash.select{
    |k,v| wanted.include?(k) }.values.to_csv}' file
```

Prints:

```
First Name,Last Name,Nickname
Angel,Romero,Romi
```

The advantage here is that full csv files are supported including quoted fields with embedded delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late and not very general, but very simple if you don't need to reuse the script:

`awk 'BEGIN {FS=", *"; OFS=","}{print $1,$3,$6}' input.csv > output.csv`